# How to spit out numbers in a range

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a spreadsheet that I'm using for a raffle, it looks like this

```
Name        Start     End  
Joe Blogs     5        10
```

I need a separate sheet which then works out the numbers between and creates separate rows for each one ie.

Joe Bloggs 5
Joe Bloggs 6
Joe Bloggs 7
etc etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible with VBa

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).